# Style class not apply for jquery append element in Laravel output

Tags: jquery, laravel

Dear I have Api output from Laravel and trying to create new checkbox list as below code.

```
data.forEach(function (subpillar,index) {
    $("#chklist").append(`<div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="${subpillar['id']}" class="form-check-input-styled">${subpillar['name']}
                                </div>
                            </div>`);
    });
```

I have `form-check-input-styled` class for specific style. But I have problem that class not apply. I'm not sure some initialization required? Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems ok to me .Also, when you append that div check your element tab if class is shown inside checkbox or not

Comment: Dear Swati, checkboxs are appended but style not render.

Comment: I am not sure what's might be wrong then.But, when you open your *element* tab and click on that checkbox you will see all style apply to that element check if its showing there or not